# I get a "Payload too large" error when uploading larger files on LAMP setup

Tags: lamp, amazon-lightsail

I have a file upload script using dropzone and I get a 413 (Payload Too Large) response when loading files over 3.5 mb. My php ini settings for post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are both set to 40M.

Is there some other restriction I'm not aware of?

I am using a LAMP (PHP 7) Certified by Bitnami 7.3.15 instance on AWS Lightsail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was unrelated to the server and turned out to be cropper.js creating rather large images.